# 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Array'.' vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to get the left character of a cell value and see if it is less than a character and if it is then add two characters ("FE") to the end. My issue seems to be related to casting string into Array. I assume I am using wrong function for this, but I am not aware. Any tips would be great. For reference, EC80 `("A" & i)` is the value of hex_value. When it gets done with the last If statement, it should be ECFE.

```
'Convert HEX values to acronyms
        Dim unique_numbers As Object
        unique_numbers = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Unique Numbers")
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim hex_value As Object
        i = 2 'Starting from two since the first row is the header
        Do Until unique_numbers.Range("A" & i) Is ""
            hex_value = unique_numbers.Range("A" & i).Value
            'unique_numbers.Range("A" & i) = convert_hex_to_acronym(unique_numbers.Range("A" & i))
            i = i + 1
            If hex_value = "0" Then
                hex_value = "0000"
            End If

            'If the first character of the string is < "F",
            'reconstruct the string by taking the first two characters and adding "FE" before comparing it.
            If LBound(hex_value, 1) < "F" Then 'Where the error occurs. hex_value = EC80(which is correct).
                hex_value = LBound(hex_value, 2) & "FE" 'hex_value should = ECFE after.
            End If
        Loop
```

Comment: LBound() doesn't make sense, presumably you meant to use Left().

Comment: @HansPassant, when I use Left I get a syntax error stating, "'Public Overloads Property Left As Integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed."

Comment: Disambiguate with `Strings.Left(hex_value, 2)`

Comment: Lol, I have been trying everything. Disambiguate as been added to my vocablulary.

Answer (score 0):

```
'If the first character of the string is < "F",'reconstruct the string by taking the first two characters and adding "FE" before comparing it.
 If Strings.Left(hex_value, 1) < "F" 
    hex_value = Strings.Left(hex_value, 2) & "FE"
 End If
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).